# Php fiscal year report, trouble with selecting proper year

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I am building a report for a client using php and codeigniter.

This report is a financial report, as such, I must reflect money collected since the beginning of the fiscal year. In this case, July 31st.

I already query the user for the date of the report, but how would I get php to know which fiscal year to take?

I have a rough idea, something along the lines of

'If Month-Day is before July 31, use current year-1
Else use current year'

But I do not know how I would code that, or if it would work, or if there is a more elegant way of doing the same thing.

Comment: where do you have the definitions of the comany's fiscal year - db, config, hard coded in the model?

Comment: I don't actually have it anywhere. Would It make it easier to have it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is the dateTime class.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
I think something like this is what you will need

```
public function getCurrentYear(DateTime $dateToCheck)
{
    $today = new DateTime();
    $currentYear = (int)$today->format('Y');
    $endFiscalYear = new DateTime('31 July'); //year left out, so will default to this year
    if($dateToCheck < $endFiscalYear){ //you need PHP >= 5.2.2 for this to work
        $currentYear--;
    }
    return $currentYear;
}
```

You can set $today by doing something like :-

```
$today = new DateTime('20 June 2011');
```

Read more in the link above

Here is a slightly different version which should be a bit more robust as it will return the fiscal year of any date you give it, not just dates in the current year.

```
function getFiscalYear(DateTime $dateToCheck)
{
    $fiscalYearEnd = '31 July';
    $year = (int)$dateToCheck->format('Y');
    $fiscalyearEndDate = new DateTime($fiscalYearEnd . ' ' . $year);
    if($dateToCheck <= $fiscalyearEndDate){
        $year--;
    }
    return $year;
}
```

use it like this :-

```
$dateToCheck = new DateTime('1 jan 2009'); // for example
$fiscalYear = getFiscalYear($dateToCheck);
```

This will return 2008

This version should work if your PHP version is < 5.2

```
function getFiscalYear($timestamp)
{
    $year = (int)date('Y', $timestamp);
    $fiscalYearEndDate = strtotime('31 July ' . $year);
    if($timestamp < $fiscalYearEndDate) $year--;
    return $year;
}
```

Use like this:-

```
$date = strtotime('1 Jan 2009');
fiscalYear = getFiscalYear($date);
```

Will return 2008

Comment: if I understand your code correctly, this will get the current year (as in 2011) compare it to July 31 of current year (as in 2011) see that is is LESS then, so the year will become 2010?

Comment: I get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in"

On the "$year = (int)$dateToCheck->format('Y');" Line

Comment: Have you declared $dateToCheck as a DateTime object? If so, what version of PHP do you have?

Comment: See edit 3 to answer this should work with verions of PHP < 5.2 (I hope).

Comment: I get this message "Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered" for line "$year = (int)date('Y', $timestamp);"

Comment: How do we declare a variable as DateTime?

Comment: See the code in Edit 2, it tells you how to do that. Try Edit 3, that may be what you need because of your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_fiscal_year($format = 'Y-m-d', $cutoff_date = '31 July') {
  $fiscal_year = strtotime($cutoff_date);
  if(time() < $fiscal_year)
    $fiscal_year = strtotime($cutoff_date .' last year');

  return date($format, $fiscal_year);

}
$fisical_year = get_fiscal_year();
$now = date('Y-m-d');
```

You then could use the function to query database with statement condition

`transcation_date between $fisical_year and $now`

Answer (score 1):

If user gives the date: `@givenDate` and you want to search in your `dateField` (which is of type `date`), you can use something like:

```
WHERE dateField BETWEEN 
          DATE( CONCAT(   YEAR(@givenDate)-(MONTH(@givenDate)<8), '-08-01' ))
      AND DATE( CONCAT( 1+YEAR(@givenDate)-(MONTH(@givenDate)<8), '-07-31' ))
```